# Does experience bonuses affect quests rewards?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've got a red gem on my helmet, giving me +19% experience for each mob I kill.
Any chance this bonus also applies to quests rewards ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the item says "Increases Experience Rewarded per Kill by 19%" I would expect that it only increases experience rewarded from killing. 
Otherwise I would expect it to say: "Increases experience gained".

Comment: Makes sense; sorry for the silly question and thanks for the smart answer :)

Answer (score 5):

No the experience bonus is per kill and does not affect quest rewards.

Answer (score 2):

No, a quest reward is not a monster, so you can't boost the quest reward experience.